# функция, которая принимает список целых чисел и возвращает True, если все числа в списке четные, в противном случае он возвращает False python

Tags: python

Почему программа работает некорректно?

```
def all_even(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: потому что последний `return True`  срабатывает после __первой__ итерации цикла и возвращает `True` вне зависимости от числа. Будьте внимательнее с отступами

Comment: @SvetaLantsman, комментарии не предназначены для размещения кода (не однострочного). Если хотите дополнить или исправить вопрос - нажмите "править" под вопросом.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы проверять числа из списка, а не индексы - сделайте или так:

```
for i in lst:
    if i % 2 != 0:
```

или так

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i] % 2 != 0:
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что, если функция получает список(массив [412,53,5146,61]), то в for нужно прописать другое, а не range(len(lst)):

```
def all_even(lst):
    count = 0 
    for i in lst: 
        if i % 2 == 0:
            if (count != int(len(lst))):
                count+=1
            else if (count==int(len(lst))):
                return True
        else:
            return False
            break
all_even(lst)
```

Вроде должно заработать

Comment: А что нетак с range(len(lst)) ? Если количество элементов не менять, то норм работает.

Comment: @Интик потому что идет перечисление от 1 до len(lst)
Потому что len - считывает количество "фрагментов" в массиве(списке)
а в задаче указано, что нужно считать из списка числа, а не от 1 до len(lst)

Comment: @Интик вот https://pythonz.net/references/named/len/
+ про range - https://python-scripts.com/range

Comment: Ок. Когда фиг поймичто в списке. Но когда там только числа, не принимается + в записи range(5): отсчёт идёт от 0 а не от 1. И чудесно подходит когда len(lst)=5

Comment: @Интик не понял в конце. Что именно?

Comment: lst=[1,2,3,4,5] . len(lst)=5 . range(5) эквивалентен range(len(lst)) . Отсчёт будет от 0 до 4 . индексы в lst тоже от 0 до 4 .  твоё утверждение что нужно писать чтото другое зацепило.

Answer (score 0):

Сравните со своим и всё поймете.

```
def all_even(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            result = True
        else:
            result = False
            break
    return result
```

Comment: спасибо, отличное решение